# invalid field found for struct main.Article's field Author

Tags: go, go-gorm

i have the following models in my application :

```
import "gorm.io/gorm"

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string
    Password string
    Email    string
    Token    string
}

type Article struct {
    gorm.Model
    Author User `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
    Text   string
    views  int
    likes  int
}
```

but i get this error :

[error] invalid field found for struct main.Article's field Author, need to define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is relatively easy, and the only missing issue is already hinted by the error: you did not provide foreign key constraint hint do GORM. Following official documentation [here](https://gorm.io/docs/constraints.html), we can simply do it like this:

```
type Article struct {
    gorm.Model
    AuthorID uint 
    Author   User `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
    Text     string
    views    int
    likes    int
}
```

So **AuthorID** field will actually highlight for GORM the field for FK that will be referencing User table.

However, you might consider adding a link in User struct to Articles, so you will be able to **[Preload](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html)** all articles of Author(s). See the link [here](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html), but leaving implementation for you to try.